# Select DateTime mysql query in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, datetime

I have the following table in my MySQL database:

| id | teplota | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12.521 | 2017-02-01 17:49:53 |
| 1 | 12.852 | 2017-02-02 17:50:53 |
| 1 | 12.852 | 2017-02-03 17:50:53 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Column `created_at` has type timestamp, here is the column definition in my `CREATE TABLE` statement:

```sql
created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

When I use this select command in DB it normally works and I get correct output

```sql
select * from ts2 where created_at >= "2017-02-01" and created_at < "2017-02-02"
```

But I have a problem if I want use it in my python code:

```py
import datetime

t1 = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1)
t2 = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 2)
t1 = str(t1)
t2 = str(t2)
c.execute("select * from ts2 where created_at >= %s and created_at < %s;" % (t1, t2))
```

I get the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 and created_at < 2017-01-31 00:00:00' at line 1

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: print the query before executing and post

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and used ' around %s to solve it:

```
sql_query = "select * from ts2 where created_at >= '%s' and created_at < '%s';" % (t1, t2)
c.execute(sql_query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed '' on the %s

Should be

`c.execute("select * from ts2 where created_at >= '%s' and created_at < '%s';" % (t1, t2))`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the "BETWEEN" comparator like so:

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM ts2 WHERE created_at BETWEEN %s and %s" % (t1, t2))
```

It was created for this type of query.

Otherwise I'm not sure why the MySQL engine would through that error. Perhaps try adding single quotes around the date placeholders?

Answer (score 0):

```
t1 = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1)
t2 = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 2)
t1 = repr(str(t1))
t2 = repr(str(t2))
c.execute("select * from ts2 where created_at >= %s and created_at < %s;" % (t1, t2))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try Converting to iso format :

```
t1 = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1)
t2 = datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 2)
t1 = str(t1.isoformat())
t2 = str(t2.isoformat())
c.execute("select * from ts2 where created_at >= %s and created_at < %s;" % (t1, t2)) 
isoformat
```